# Usar una Label desde una Clase en Swift

Tags: poo, ios, swift, xcode

Estoy iniciándome en Swift y soy muy novato en esto. Tengo una duda que seguro os parecerá una chorrada, ahí va:

Tengo una *Label* conectada en el *Viewcontroller* pero no se como mandarle información desde otra *Clase* distinta. Desde el propio *Viewcontroller* si que sé trabajar con ella pero no encuentro la forma de enviarle información desde mi *Clase*. Lo único que se me ocurre es crear un *Objeto* en mi clase y acceder a la *Label* pero me da un error al compilar.

Gracia de antemano, saludos!

---

No logro conseguir hacer que funcione, no se realmente que estoy haciendo mal.
Yo tengo mi ViewController que se crea por defecto al iniciar un nuevo proyecto en Xcode. Tengo una Label conectada y desde ese ViewControler puedo usarla sin problema. Ahora bien, tengo otra Clase simple desde la que quiero mandar un valor a esa Label. Simplifico mi problema:

```
Class MiClase {
  var numUno = 10
  var numDos = 30
  var resultado = numUno + numDos *// Este "resultado" es el que me gustaria enviar a 
                                     la label.*
}
```

Desde MiClase, me gustaria poder lo siguiente:

```
miLabel.text = "\(resultado)"
```

Ya que la unica forma que tengo de poder mandar esa informacion a la Label es instanciando MiClase en ViewControler y llamando al valor:

```
miLabel.text = "\(MiClase.resultado)"
```

Cosa que no quiero hacer porque tengo demasiados datos y funciones en MiClase y no quiero llenar ViewController con demasiado código.
Trato de utilizar los segues pero no consigo que me muestre los valores y el problema es que no se que estoy haciendo mal. Saludos y gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar los `segues`. Lo agregas desde el `viewController` padre al `viewController` hijo o viceversa.
Entonces sobreescribes la siguiente función:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let detalleScripts = segue.destination as! TuViewController //agregas una variable de tipo tu view controller (hijo)
        
        detalleScripts.tuLabel.text = "El valor"//accedes al label de ese view controller y le asignas el valor
    }
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias. Lo intentaré así a ver si lo contigo. Ese procedimiento tiene algún nombre en concreto? Es que leí en algún foro que hablaba de “castear “ la clase, no se si será lo mismo. Lo digo más que nada para buscar más información al respecto y afianzar conceptos. Gracias de muevo

Comment: Los `viewController` son clases, entendí que quieres enviar valores de una a otra; de igual manera si tuvieras una clase simple puedes usar esa función porque los segues son los conectores para cambiar de vistas.

Comment: Lo de castear se hace aquí `let detalleScripts = segue.destination as! TuViewController` estás diciendo que tu `segue` sea del tipo de clase `TuViewController`. Intenta y me comentas.

Comment: https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/ revisa esta pagina

Comment: No logro hacerlo funcionar. Lo explico en una respuesta a mi comentario arriba

Comment: Entonces no entiendo tu pregunta. La forma fácil sería que utilices `UserDefaults` es parecido a las variables de sesiones que se pueden utilizar en cualquier lado. Creas y asignas un valor y luego lo obtienes en el lugar que necesites.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo desde la vista (ViewController) instanciar el objeto de tu clase (MyClass) llamar su función de calculo y obtener el resultado para mostrarlo en el label de tu Viewcontroller, si quieres enviar ese resultado a otro ViewController en tu ViewController inicial puedes crear la instancia del segundo viewController y enviarle como parámetro el resultado para que sea mostrado allá, sin embargo, de acuerdo a lo que entiendo que necesitas puedes intentar lo siguiente:

En tu clase del ViewController tienes la propiedad objClass que es de tipo MyClass

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    
    var objClass: MyClass?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        configView()
    }

    private func configView() {
        myLabel.text = String((objClass?.result ?? 0))
    }
}
```

Desde tu clase llamas el ViewController

```
import UIKit

class MyClass {

    var numberOne: Int
    var numberTwo: Int
    var result: Int = 0
    
    init(numberOne: Int, numberTwo: Int) {
        self.numberOne = numberOne
        self.numberTwo = numberTwo
    }

    func calculate() {
        self.result = self.numberOne + self.numberTwo
    }

    func showResult() {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "YourStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController") as? MyViewController;
        viewController?.objClass = self
       let navigationController: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController!)
       navigationController..pushViewController(viewController, animated: true);
    }
}
```

Desde alguna parte...:

```
let obj = MyClass(numberOne: 5, numberTwo: 10)
obj.calculate()
obj.showResult()
```

Comment: Genial, volveré a intentarlo con esa forma. Entiendo entonces que la única manera (o la más correcta) de trabajar en un Viewcontroller, con valores y funciones definidos en una Clase, es instanciando en el Viewcontroller la Clase en cuestión y llamando a sus respectivas funciones y valores, verdad? Entiendo también, corrígeme si me equivoco, que los segues entonces son conectores más recomendados para enviar datos de un Viewcontroller a otro?

Comment: Depende de la funcionalidad que estes necesitando, pero para el caso que tienes creo que es la mejor forma, ejemplo: (Una calculadora sencilla) Tu tienes un ViewController con dos campos de texto (para ingresar dos números) y un botón, cuando el usuario presione el botón obtienes los datos de los campos de texto y se los pasas a una función de tu clase para que se realice la operación y te retorne el resultado, posteriormente en tu ViewController puedes abrir otro ViewController y le envías como parámetro el resultado para mostrarlo en allá, de esa manera separas un poco la vista de tu lógica.

Comment: Para llamar tu otro ViewController y enviarle el resultado puedes usar segues o puedes enviarle el dato en un argumento que tenga el segundo ViewController y posteriormente cuando se cargue ese ViewController en la función ViewDidLoad (Que pertenece al ciclo de vida de los UIViewController)  puedes asignarlo a un UILabel que tengas.

Comment: Te recomiendo estos artículos https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-pass-data-between-two-view-controllers , https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/